# How to launch my Flutter app without the host computer?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I wanted to know how to launch my Flutter app without the host computer on my iOS 14+ devices. Because I disconnected to my host computer and it gave me some error, so that I don't have to go back to my Mac everytime and rebuild that app.

Comment: You will need to build the application and install it to the device. This is different from the `flutter run` command. Take a look at the docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just run this command in your IDE (I did it with VSCode)

```
flutter run --release
```

It worked for me!

Comment: You should mark this as the answer; worked for me, too!